# How to show/hide one element from data array rendered dynamically with react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Still fairly new on understanding how to use React hooks. I have a list of questions that was dynamically rendered from an array of objects. When I click on a question, I want only that question's answer to show. Right now, when I click on a question, all of the answers show at the same time.

This is the file containing the data:

```
export const personalFaq = [
    {
        question: 'Question 1',
        answer: 'Answer 1 '
    },
    {
        question: 'Question 2',
        answer: 'Answer 2'
    },
    {
        question: 'Question 3',
        answer: 'Answer 3'
    },
    {
        question: 'Question 4',
        answer: 'Answer 4'
    },
    {
        question: 'Question 5',
        answer: 'Question 5'
    }

]
```

This is my component for rendering my list of questions:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { personalFaq } from '../../questionData/personalFaq';

const Faq = () => {

    const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false);
    const onClick = () => setShowAnswer(!showAnswer);
        
    const renderQuestion = (question, index) => {
        
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <p><span onClick={onClick}>
                    {!showAnswer ? (<i className="fas fa-angle-down m-1"></i>) : (<i className="fas fa-angle-up"></i>)}
                    </span>{question.question}</p>
                {showAnswer && (<p>{question.answer}</p>) }
            </div>
        )

    }

    return(
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Container>
                    <h1>FAQ</h1>
                    <Row>
                        {personalFaq.map(renderQuestion)}
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Faq;
```

Image of what is currently rendered:
[Dynamically Rendered List of Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewWUd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all! I added a number to each question since they are fixed and use that as the id. I was able to solve it with the code below:

```
const Faq = () => {

    // States to control toggle effect on faq
    const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false);
    const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null);
    
    //Will render one question and show/hide answer when span is clicked
    const renderQuestion = (question) => {
        const onClick = () => {
            setCurrentId(question.id);
            setShowAnswer(!showAnswer);
        }

        return (
            <div key={question.id}>
                <p>
                    <span onClick={onClick}>
                    {showAnswer ? (<i className="fas fa-angle-up"></i>) : (<i className="fas fa-angle-down m-1"></i>)}
                    </span>{question.question}</p>
                {currentId === question.id && showAnswer === true && (<p>{question.answer}</p>) }
            </div>
        )

    }

    //Container where all the questions will be rendered dynamically
    return(
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Container>
                    <h1>FAQ</h1>
                    <Row>
                        {personalFaq.map(renderQuestion)}
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set 1 boolean value for tracking the visibility for all of the items, so if it's turned to `true` all of them will be displayed.

you also don't pass any parameters to the `onClick` function that can track which one of the items needs to be displayed or hide

Answer (score 0):

Your state is declared and used within the Faq component, thus it affects all renders within that component that uses it.

In this case the simplest solution is to create a separate component for `RenderQuestion` that manages its own state and thus should only expand within itself.

Something like this the below example should solve your issue.
`RenderQuestion` is now its own component that manages its own state. It will be rendered for each item in the `personalFaq` array, and each item will have its own instance of the component with its own state management.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { personalFaq } from '../../questionData/personalFaq';

const RenderQuestion = (question) => {
    const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false);
    const onClick = () => setShowAnswer(!showAnswer);
    return (
        <div>
            <p><span onClick={onClick}>
                {!showAnswer ? (<i className="fas fa-angle-down m-1"></i>) : (<i className="fas fa-angle-up"></i>)}
            </span>{question.question}</p>
            {showAnswer && (<p>{question.answer}</p>)}
        </div>
    )
}

const Faq = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <Container>
                    <h1>FAQ</h1>
                    <Row>
                        {personalFaq.map((question, index) => <RenderQuestion key={index} question={question} />)}
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Faq;
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to be able to see an answer at the time, then you should probably add an id to every item and then use that to set an activeQuestionId and only display that (I left you an example). If you want to be able to see answers independently of each. other, then you should create a local state in a separate component for each row.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { personalFaq } from '../../questionData/personalFaq';

const Faq = () => {
  const [activeQuestionId, setActiveQuestionId] = useState(null)

  return (
    <Container>
      <Container>
        <Container>
          <h1>FAQ</h1>
          <Row>
            {personalFaq.map(({ id, question, answer }) => (
              <div key={id}>
                <p>
                  <span onClick={() => setActiveQuestionId(id)}>
                    <i className={`fas ${activeQuestionId === id ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down m-1'}`}></i>
                  </span>
                  {question}
                </p>
                {activeQuestionId === id && <p>{answer}</p>}
              </div>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Faq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { personalFaq } from '../../questionData/personalFaq';

const Faq = () => {
  const [activeQuestionId, setActiveQuestionId] = useState("");

  function onClickHandler(id){
   if (activeQuestionId === id) {
      setActiveQuestionId("");
    } else {
      setActiveQuestionId(id);
    }
}
  return (
    <Container>
      <Container>
        <Container>
          <h1>FAQ</h1>
          <Row>
            {personalFaq.map(({ id, question, answer }) => (
              <div key={id}>
                <p>
                  <span onClick={() => onClickHandler(id)}>
                    <i className={`fas ${activeQuestionId === id ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down m-1'}`}></i>
                  </span>
                  {question}
                </p>
                {activeQuestionId === id && <p>{answer}</p>}
              </div>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Faq
```

Comment: the answer is similar to Ignacio Elias. If you want to improve or have any suggestions feel free to add a comment to an answer.